# Need to remove the duplicate names

Tags: sql

As on the image, I was trying to combine 2 tables, 1st table contains the test name, and the other contains the `test description` and `expected values`.
With my SQL knowledge and try to combine two tables, I'm getting test name duplicate on each raw.

But technically, I need just one line from the TS_NAME. All the highlighted TS_NAMEs should not available for my query output.

Can someone please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: ```SELECT DISTINCT``` maybe?

Comment: From your provided example, each test name (`TS_NAME`), might have 1 or many `DS_DESCRIPTION` and `DS_EXPECTED` values. **On which condition you would keep the single description, expected row for that test name?** E.g: selecting latest the ds description, expected row based on creation timestamp for example.

Comment: DISTINCT is not going to work.

Comment: On which condition you would keep the single description, expected row for that test name?, Only condition is if the same TS_NAME appear in the out put, only one should be visible. @ThangLeQuoc appreciate your comment.

Comment: May I know the database engine that you're using? Is it MySQL, or SQL Server, or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the **RANK()** window function is your friend

[A guide to use RANK() in SQL Server](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-rank-function/)

Since you didn't specify the database engine being used, so I pick **Postgres** for [the demonstration here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rw5JvXF21oCQWZNJcMFnVj/28), the `RANK()` should be available in many common database engine we're using nowadays with pretty common syntax, so you should have no problem converting this to suite your database engine

I prepared a sample data table name `sample_outputs`, representing the existing output you have, after executing your query (you may replace this with the SQL query that you're using, as long as it still produces three required columns: `ts_name`, `ds_description` and `ds_expected`)

The output have multiple row for each `ts_name`.
**`sample_outputs` table**

| ts_name | ds_description | ds_expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name_a1 | description_a1_1 | expected_a1_1 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_1 | expected_a2_1 |
| name_a1 | description_a1_2 | expected_a1_2 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_2 | expected_a2_2 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_3 | expected_a2_3 |
| name_a3 | description_a3_1 | expected_a3_1 |
| name_a3 | description_a3_2 | expected_a3_2 |

First, **we're going to get the rank number of each row in each ts_name group**. This is specified by partitioning by the `ts_name` column. Since you don't specify the priority order so I use ORDER BY all three columns `ts_name`, `ds_description`, `ds_expected`. This will rate the rank of the record in each ts_name group by the order of its appearance (first one has the highest rank)

```
SELECT ts_name, ds_description, ds_expected, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ts_name ORDER BY ts_name, ds_description, ds_expected) as record_rank 
from 
-- you can replace <sample_outputs> with your existing query,
-- make sure that it produces three columns ts_name, ds_description and ds_expected
sample_outputs;
```

This will give us the rank of each record in the `ts_name` partition, with it appearance order.

| ts_name | ds_description | ds_expected | record_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_a1 | description_a1_1 | expected_a1_1 | 1 |
| name_a1 | description_a1_2 | expected_a1_2 | 2 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_1 | expected_a2_1 | 1 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_2 | expected_a2_2 | 2 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_3 | expected_a2_3 | 3 |
| name_a3 | description_a3_1 | expected_a3_1 | 1 |
| name_a3 | description_a3_2 | expected_a3_2 | 2 |

Then finally we'll just need to create an additional query to wrap the output of our rank query above. This time, we get the `ts_name description expected` record with the `record_rank = 1` only.

```
SELECT ts_name, ds_description, ds_expected
FROM
(
SELECT ts_name, ds_description, ds_expected, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ts_name ORDER BY ts_name, ds_description, ds_expected) as record_rank 
from 
-- you can replace <sample_outputs> with your existing query,
-- make sure that it produces three columns ts_name, ds_description and ds_expected
sample_outputs
) output_with_rank
WHERE output_with_rank.record_rank = 1;
```

| ts_name | ds_description | ds_expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name_a1 | description_a1_1 | expected_a1_1 |
| name_a2 | description_a2_1 | expected_a2_1 |
| name_a3 | description_a3_1 | expected_a3_1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle for this question here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rw5JvXF21oCQWZNJcMFnVj/28)

Comment: This is so informative.Thanks.But just a small query , when I compare  2nd and 3rd tables, If i follow your approach "description_a1_2","description_a2_1" ..etc are missing rite?

Comment: @user2728409 yes, since a ts_name can have one or many ds_description-expected so following your requirement, I only keep the first ds_description-expected record.
If you wish to concatenate all the `ds_description` and `ds_expected` into a single field, please learn about `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.
The output will be: 
name_a1 | description_a1_1, description_a1_2 | expected_a1_1, expected_a1_2